# Como utilizar ícone em um UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Como eu coloco um ícone em um `UIButton` através do `.storyboard`?

Através do `.storyboard` tem as opções do `UIButton` entre elas tem a opção `image` onde consigo informar um caminho para uma imagem para o botão. Porém eu gostaria de usar os ícones default do iOS.

O iOS possui ícones *default* assim como no android? Ou terei de criar um `.jpg` ou `.png` para cada um dos meus ícones?

Comment: Voce pode baixar o programa sketch 3, nele possui todos os botões, ícones, e qualquer tipo de design nativo do iOS e salvado como png para usar no seu botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os ícones de sistema são utilizados a partir da classe [`UIBarButtonSystemItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem), consequentemente somente com o componente `UIBarButtonItem` que estão disponíveis na barra de navegação ou *toolbar*.

Ou seja, não é possível utilizar os ícones de sistema com `UIButton`. Dê uma olhada neste [guia de referência](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW33) da Apple para design.